# Install Ubuntu without creating a new user

Tags: system-installation, users

After booting my system from the USB with the Ubuntu 20.04 installation, it prompts me to create a new user.

Is there a way around it? More specifically, I'd like to loggin from my existing user right away.

Does that even make sense? Or should every machine have it's own user?

Thanks in advance,
Ben

Comment: If you are prompted to create a new user, then you are *installing*, and any previous users have been deleted. There is no "existing" user anymore. A user on some other machine is relevant only if you have an identity server on your network.

Comment: I do a lot of experimenting with Ubuntu installs, sometimes dozens a week on multiple USB's. I always use the same username and password and I rarely get confused. I usually insert Username and Password as part of the install process, (right after Location).

Answer (score 0):

The USB experience is a give it a go - if you like it you need to have a user for a permanent install.
Fantastic you want to install - so same details  (if you want/appropriate) and off you go for a permanent solution on your machine.

If you are already running Ubuntu then `sudo do-release-upgrade` after a full update....

YMMV (if this helps a vote would be nice)